# Error when updating a database table with pymssql and a python dictionary

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

I am trying to write data in a dictionary back into a SQL Server database table with `pymssql`.

But I am getting this error:

> ValueError: more placeholders in sql than params available

Here is my code:

```py
cursor = conn.cursor()
for key in dictW:
    x = dictW[key]
    sql = 'UPDATE tablename SET col = %s WHERE %s = @url '
    cursor.executemany(sql, (key, x))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to execute your queries one by one but are using `executemany()`. You should consider using a simple `execute()` instead:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for key in dictW:
    x = dictW[key]
    sql = 'UPDATE tablename SET col = %s WHERE %s = @url '
    cursor.execute(sql, (key, x))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

If you want to use `executemany()`, you should make a list of tuples like this:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
params = [(k, v) for k, v in dictW.items()]
sql = 'UPDATE tablename SET col = %s WHERE %s = @url '
cursor.executemany(sql, params)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I am still new to this and make these mistakes.